# Is it necessary to "clean" SBT before "stage" for production builds?

Tags: scala, jenkins, continuous-integration, sbt

We are using Jenkins and SBT pluging to build, test and deploy our application. I see everywhere that people use "clean" command before "test" or "stage" which leads to very long compile times.

Is it necessary to clean everything for each build? What is the risk of using the incremental compiler for production builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the build script and/or command line to `sbt` have not changed then it should not be necessary to do `clean`.

I have been using `Spark` for several years - and it is one of the most complex sbt builds you can find. It works just fine to avoid doing `clean` as long as the build process itself (as embodied in the project/sbt build artifacts and the sbt command line) are the same as previous runs.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a matter of taste. For continuous integration builds, it's ok to rely on the incremental compiler; if something fails I can investigate quite quickly.

But if, for whatever reason, the incremental compiler decides to ignore some changes (and it already happened to me in development), you may get some difficult bugs to resolve.

So, if you want something that's reproducible from a fresh code checkout; just run "clean" before everything else.

Most of the time, I configure jenkins with two build tasks: test builds, triggered by code changes, and packaging builds targeted for deployment and triggered periodically (or manually in some cases, with automatic deployment).